# calculate ORs at fixed interaction levels for logistic regression?

Tags: r, sas

SAS has a nice way to analyze ORs from interactions like below, which I found [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/seminars/analyzing-and-visualizing-interactions/):

```
proc logistic data = exercise descending;
class prog / param=glm order=internal;
model satisfied = prog|hours / expb;
oddsratio prog / at(hours = 1.51 2 2.5), at(prog=all);
store logit;
run;
```

where `hours` is continuous and `prog` is a three-level categorical variable.
I found a way to calculate ORs in R comparing unit increase of hours at the different levels of `prog` which returns the same output in SAS, but I can't find a way to compare `prog` at specified hours in R.

Comment: `emmeans` package?

Comment: yeah used that for finding OR of hours at different prog but can't vice versa :/

Comment: I think you can, if you look at the `at` argument to `ref_grid` ...

Comment: I'm definitely not experienced with emmeans, are you suggesting something like: ```test <- ref_grid(mylogit, at = list(hours = c(1.5, 2.0, 2.5)))
emmeans(test, ~ hours, by="prog")```  but I think my emmeans statement is wrong

Comment: I'm not actually sure off the top of my head. I just think it's possible.

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks so much for the direction... absolutely amazing.

Comment: great!  please post an answer (self-answering is encouraged) as soon as you're allowed.